# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment declared target fragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager

Tags: java, android

I show a dialog with this code

```
    MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
    myDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(targetFragment, 0);
    Utils.showDialog(targetFragment.getFragmentManager(), myDialogFragment, DIALOG_TAG);
```

This is `showDialog`

```
public static void showDialog(FragmentManager fragmentManager, DialogFragment dialog, String dialogTag) {
    dismissDialog(fragmentManager, dialogTag);

    dialog.show(fragmentManager.beginTransaction(), dialogTag);
}

public static void dismissDialog(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String dialogTag) {
    Fragment dialogFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(dialogTag);
    if (dialogFragment != null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(dialogFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

And this works. I launch the app, the main activity is started, and the `targetFragment` is shown. I press the button and I see the dialog. I can go to background, switch to another app, go back and the app is still working and the dialog is there. I go into development options and enable "Don't keep activities" then I repeat. Still no crash. The app has several deeplinks. I tried to launch the dialog, to go notes and press on a link. The corresponding screen opens and when I press back `targetFragment` is shown along with `MyDialogFragment` and no crash. But on crashlytics there are some crashes with the following stack trace.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.name/com.some.package.of.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyDialogFragment{******* #* dialog_tag} declared target fragment TargetFragment{*******} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2740)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2801)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)

Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyDialogFragment{******* #* dialog_tag} declared target fragment TargetFragment{*******} that does not belong to this FragmentManager!
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1352)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1750)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1819)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2590)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2377)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2332)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2239)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3231)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3181)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:572)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1249)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6887)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2703)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2801)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6356)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:791)
```

I tried it on Api 23 and 24, on emulator and on Samsung Galaxy S6. And it works without crash.

Comment: this post says it's Android 8 bug, I forgot to mention the crashes happen on Android 4, 6, 7, 8. Mostly on Android 7.0

Comment: Did you find a solution OP ? I experience the same

Comment: The same on Android 7.0. Solution?